# Spree how to override Skeleton detected screen width?

Tags: responsive-design, spree, skeleton-css-boilerplate

Is it possible and easy to force my Spree app / the user's browser to ignore Skeleton width adjustments and always assume a 960px wide browser, just making the user scroll right?

I've created and deployed a basic, functional ecommerce app.  Being an absolute novice, I was unaware of responsive design.  So, now, my site works well with a large view, but turns into a jumble at widths < 960px.  I'm hoping for a quick patch while I do some learning and redesign the layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can set an explicit width on the body:

```
body {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto; /* center the body */
}
```

Comment: Your suggestion didn't work for some reason.  I ended up just overriding the Skeleton CSS by pasting the original 960px wide styling into a later sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Skeleton is based on fixed widths.  Every columns has a px-value width.  Just setting the body to a different width won't work.

You'll have to edit skeleton.css.  Determine the column widths and divide by 960 to get percentages.  Then decide what body width you want to use, and set the column widths to the respective percentage times the new width.